# Deploying round-robin to Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I am struggling to find any material on deploying round-robin lb to my k8s cluster.

Does anyone have any useful links or information to share that I could use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kubernetes has already a type of service for that, if what you are looking for a neat solution check this [load balancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) service section.

If you want to use an external load balancer, [check this out](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/)